# How to make Kendo chart legend with circle icon?

Tags: javascript, kendo-ui, telerik, kendo-chart

I am seeing other answers but it's in triangle shape. What I really need is to do a circle icon like in the picture below:

[image: Legend with circle icons]

I tried customizing the "kendo.geometry.Rect" in this [Dojo example](https://dojo.telerik.com/AkajogIG) by the [Circle Geometry API](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/geometry/circle). But I need help in understanding what I supposed to do.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You Circle Geometry only defines center and radius. You then need to use the **[drawing.Circle](https://docs.telerik.com/kendo-ui/api/javascript/drawing/circle)**:

```
visual: function (e) {
  // get color of current marker and label
  var color = e.options.markers.background;     
  var labelColor = e.options.labels.color;
  var rect = new kendo.geometry.Rect([0, 0], [100, 50]);
  var layout = new kendo.drawing.Layout(rect, {
    spacing: 5,
    alignItems: "center"
  });
  // create a circle geometry centered at x=10, y=5, with a radius of 5
  var CircGeometry = new kendo.geometry.Circle([10, 5], 5);
  // draw the circle using the geometry and set the color (could have no stroke)
  var MarkerCircle = new kendo.drawing.Circle(CircGeometry, {
    stroke: { color: color, width: 1 },
    fill: { color: color }
  });
  //Create the text label
  var label = new kendo.drawing.Text(e.series.name, [0, 0], {
    fill: {
      color: labelColor
    }
  });

  //Add circle and label to layout object
  layout.append(MarkerCircle, label);
  layout.reflow()

  return layout;
}
```

Comment: Thank you very much, it worked! Though if you have some time to add comments to your snippet it will be a great help to me to understand  :)

Comment: @xawi, i added comments